# How do i append some text to pipe without temporary file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipe

I am trying to get the max version number from a directory where i have several versions of one program

for example if output of ls is

```
something01_1.sh
something02_0.1.2.sh
something02_0.1.sh
something02_1.1.sh
something02_1.2.sh
something02_2.0.sh
something02_2.1.sh
something02_2.3.sh
something02_3.1.2.sh
something.sh
```

I am getting the max version number with the following -

```
ls somedir | grep some_prefix | cut -d '_' -f2 | sort -t '.' -k1 -r | head -n 1
```

Now if at the same time i want to check it with the version number which i already have in the system, whats the best way to do it...

in bash i got this working (if 2.5 is the current version)

```
(ls somedir | grep some_prefix | cut -d '_' -f2; echo 2.5) | sort -t '.' -k1 -r | head -n 1
```

is there any other correct way to do it?

EDIT: In the above example some_prefix is something02.

EDIT: Actual Problem here is

```
(ls smthing; echo more) | sort
```

is it the best way to merge output of two commands/program for piping into third.

Comment: Did you consider using a real version control system like `git` ????

Comment: That decision was not mine to make.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution. The best way it seems is using process substitution.

```
cat <(ls smthing) <(echo more) | sort
```

for my version example

```
cat <(ls somedir | grep some_prefix | cut -d '_' -f2) <(echo 2.5) | sort -t '.' -k1 -r | head -n 1
```

for the benefit of future readers, I recommend - please drop the lure of one-liner and use glob as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) suggested.

Almost similar question is asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/317819/passing-two-arguments-to-a-command-using-pipes).

more info about [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Answer (score 2):

Is the following code more suitable to what you're looking for:

```
#/bin/bash

highest_version=$(ls something* | sort -V | tail -1 | sed "s/something02_\|\.sh//g")
current_version=$(echo $0 | sed "s/something02_\|\.sh//g")

if [ $current_version > $highest_version ]; then
    echo "Uh oh! Looks like we need to update!";
fi
```

Comment: Does that accomplish what you need?

Comment: are you sure? In every shell I know $0 is the name of the running program, not it's version number. Good luck to all!

Comment: @Paul - Sorry. But i think you misunderstood my question. What i meant is i want to get the max version number among the files present in the directory and the one i am running. I am not doing this check in the program in question. as mentioned in the example. I am running version 2.5 of something02, which may or may not be present in the update directory. And i need to figure out if the current running is the latest or not and if i need replacement. replacement is expensive for me. i cant just start the latest without a check first.

Comment: Ahhh.. I see what you mean

Comment: :) thanks for the -V tip. I didn't know about that. that sure is going to reduce the code for me a bit. But the problem still remains the same. i am looking for alternate to using bash grouping. (ls smthing; echo more) | sort

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: @chepner - are you saying that because how how ls behaves different when piped?

Comment: @paul - yes i am doing something along those lines right now. but the problem is i cant do a simple numeric check with versions number. they are not actually decimal (3.2.1). sometimes string such as beta.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs explains the problems with, and alternatives to, parsing the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
#! /bin/bash

lastversion() { # prefix
  local prefix="$1" a=0 b=0 c=0 r f vmax=0

  for f in "$prefix"* ; do
    test -f "$f" || continue
    read a b c r <<< $(echo "${f#$prefix} 0 0 0" | tr -C '[0-9]' ' ')
    v=$(((a*100+b)*100+c))
    if ((v>vmax)); then vmax=$v; fi
  done
  echo $vmax  
}

lastversion "something02"
```

It will print: 30102

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ended up doing something same in perl. But the question still remains open. How to do  ### (ls smthing; echo more) | sort ### with only pipes.